# how to "test" a function and repeat it if is not executed? in R

Tags: r, function, loops

I have to run a function over a list of elements (in R). This function estimates the parameters of a model by maximum likelihood. To run the function, I need to give a set of initial parameter values, which then will be optimised by the algorithm.

Then here is my problem:

I want to randomise the initial parameter values every time I execute the function over each element of my list. I do it with the function runif(). HOWEVER, not all combinations of the initial parameters seem to work (it gives an error). In this case, I would like to execute again and again the function over that element of the list, trying different starting values, until I get the combination of initial parameter values that make the function work. Only then the loop can continue to the next element of the list.

Could you please give me some ideas of how can I tackle this problem?

thank very much in advance.

Tina.

Comment: Take a look at `try()` function help.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that, given suitable initial parameters, your optimization algorithm will only evaluate the function in suitable points as well? If not, then your problem is a little more complicated than stated.

Comment: BTW, a simple solution, if you're trying to maximize a positive function (or minimize a negative one), is to wrap the function to return `0` if the arguments are not suitable. Using @GavinSimpson 's code below: `g <- function(x) { res <- try(f(x)); ifelse(inherits(res, "try-error"), 0, res) }` Assuming `f` returns a length-one vector.

Comment: Thanks Ferdinand, indeed it is guaranteed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the call that generates the error in `try` or `tryCatch`.

In pseudo code:

```
out <- vector(mode = "list", length = 10)
for (i in seq_along(out)) {
  res <- try(...function call here...)
  ## res contains the actual error msg in object of class "try-error"
  while(inherits(res, "try-error")) {
    res <- try(...function call here...)
  }
  out[[i]] <- res
}
```

or using `repeat`

```
out <- vector(mode = "list", length = 10)
for (i in seq_along(out)) {
  repreat {
    res <- try(...function call here...)
    if(!inherits(res, "try-error"))
      break
  }
  out[[i]] <- res
}
```

<strike>You'll need to arrange `out` to be the required length or type of object to hold the results, as you see fit, and whether you need to record if the function failed (as the example above does with `NA`) or not will depend on what you are doing. Without an explicit example, that is the best you'll get.</strike>

Read `?try` and also look at `?tryCatch`, the latter is a more general mechanism for trapping errors. `try` itself is implemented using `tryCatch` for example...

Comment: Thank you Gavin, but if I understand this properly, this is a way to record the elements that failed (they will appear with the value "NA" in the vector "out"). However, what I am searching is a way to re-execute the function on an element that fails (as in another execution, other starting values are gonna be picked, which could make the function work).

Comment: Another important detail is that the output of the function is in itself a list, so I guess the outputs have to be stored in a "list of lists"?

Comment: OK, I'll update, but for future reference, this is why we ask for reproducible examples or at least code.

Comment: Updated now in light of comments. I think I got the `repeat` version right - not something I use much. HTH. I've also changed this to store the output in a list.

Comment: sorry, it was an endless piece of code, that's why I didn't put it.